# Creating new model instance through views.py including args through a url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a new model instance every time a url is accessed. so far, I have the function working in my views.py, but when the new model instance is created, the fields are empty  (because I have not specified what I'd like in those fields in views.)

**views.py**

```
def session_invent(self):
    session = Session() # I can add field data in here, but I want to get it via the URL
    session.save()
    messages.success(self, f'session invented!')
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('session/invent/', views.session_invent, name="session-invent"),
```

**models.py**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    qid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aid = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    session_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def qid_plus_aid(self):
        return '{}_{}'.format(self.qid, self.aid)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uid

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('session-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**Ok, so here is what i am trying to pull off:**

right now if i enter `mywebsite.com/session/invent/` a new Session model instance is created with empty fields. Is there a way I can fill in those fields with args in the URL? For example, something like...

`mywebsite.com/session/invent/?uid=test_uid&cid=test_cid&qid=test_qid&aid=test_aid`

---

Finished Answered code:

From the answer below here is how the updated views.py should look:

```
def session_invent(request):
    session = Session.objects.create(
        uid=request.GET['uid'],
        cid=request.GET['cid'],
        qid=request.GET['qid'],
        aid=request.GET['aid']
    )
    messages.success(request, f'session invented from URL!')
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

So, If I enter the following URL, a new record is created in my database with the values in each field set from the URL:

```
mywebsite.com/session/invent/?uid=test_uid&cid=test_cid&qid=test_qid&aid=test_aidz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the parameters are stored in the *querystring*, and you can use `request.GET` for a dictionary-like representation of the querystring, so:

```
def session_invent(request):
    session = Session.objects.create(
        uid=request.GET['uid'],
        cid=request.GET['cid'],
        qid=request.GET['qid'],
        aid=request.GET['aid']
    )
    messages.success(request, f'session invented!')
    return redirect('blog-home')
```

This will raise a HTTP 500 in case one of the keys is missing in the `request.GET`. You can use [**`request.GET.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) to access an element with an optional default value.

A GET request is however not supposed to have side effects. It is furthermore quite *odd* for a POST request to have a querystring.

Comment: Thank you so much! this answer worked with a few minor tweaks: added commas after each field in the ```Session.objects.create``` list. Added ```session.save()``` to actually save the record to the database.  Also, I had to switch the ```message.success``` first arg to ```request``` instead of ```self```. I'll add finished code to the edit.

Comment: @ThomasByers: normally `Session.objects.create(..)` will save it to the database already. But indeed, there were apparently some syntax errors :S

Comment: Oh you're correct. I tried it without the ```Session.save()``` and it worked. Thanks again!